# Azure template how do we change the resource name based on resource group location?

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

I am working on a common template where it uses different vnet in each Region. How do we change the template based on location, set vnet name.

Can we use if (resourcegroup.location) ?

Comment: do you want to have if/else statements inside you ARM template? or do you simply want to append the resource group location to the resource name? if the latter is the case, then you can simply use variables to populate the desired string, and then use that variable for your resource name. Something similar to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-location?tabs=azure-powershell#use-location-parameter

Comment: It is inside template. Use  vnet1 if location is 'Eastus' else  vnet2. How do we use that for two or more locations?

Comment: You might be able to do this with ARM functions with if conditions. see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if

Comment: yes, tried same. it is not working. I am not finding anyone used in quick start  templates, It is not a unusual used case.

Comment: Hi! Can you add the Arm template to see what may be happening? I do something similar in one of mine.

Comment: [if(condition, true value, false value)]
Based on resource group location, use vnet for EastUS, or use vnet1 for others.. If this works, I would like to extend for other locations.
"vnetname": "[if(equals(ResourceGroup.location),'EastUS','vnet'),'vnet1'))]"

Comment: In this template, based on location,  requirement is to change vnet name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-location?tabs=azure-powershell#use-location-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I know what it's happening to you, you are not comparing against a valid value, "EastUs" it's not the resourceGroup().location, in this case is "eastus". You can make a test deployment ande see the output to check that kind of values.

I have modified the template that you have passed in the comments to do what you wanted.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[if(equals(resourceGroup().location,'eastus'),'eastusstorageaccount','noteastusstorageaccount')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    }
  }
}
```

To do what you want in a dynamic way, I would try to encode the name of the vbnet. Something like this:

1. eastusvbnet
2. westeuropevbnet
3. uksouthvbnet

And in the variable I will put this:

```
"variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat(resourceGroup().location,'vbnet')]"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. What's the best practice to use same template across multiple regions choosing the resources in that location?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Can you mark the answer like valid? About the best practice  to use the same template, im not sure. Normally when I change the location I will redeploy all the resources...

Comment: In case of common resources (shared), we need to use the existing ones.

Comment: Then I don't really know, when we have to do something like that, we always try to play with the names of the existing ones , to be able to format the correct name of the resources you want to use. You can chain several "Ifs", but if you have a lot of diferent locations this will be not maintainable. You can pass the  vbnet resourcename. Good luck!!